# remove duplicate records in postgres where all records are duplicate

Tags: postgresql

My postgres table model have exactly duplicate record, I need to write a query to delete them.

id  | model | model_id | dependent_on_model

-----+-------+----------+--------------------

1 | Card  |       72 | Metric
   1 | Card  |       72 | Metric
   2 | Card  |       79 | Metric
   2 | Card  |       79 | Metric
   3 | Card  |       83 | Metric
   3 | Card  |       83 | Metric
   5 | Card  |       86 | Metric

using Cte is not helping as i am getting the error 
relation "cte" does not exist.

Please suggest a query which delete the duplicate row and i will have just 4 distinct records at the end.

Comment: You want to leave one and remove the other?

Comment: yes, so that at the end i will have just the distinct record.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to duplicate the table in a `TEMPORARY TABLE WITH OIDS`. This way you have some other id to distinguish the two identical rows.

**Idea:**

1. Duplicate the data with another ID in a temporary table.
2. Remove duplicates in temporary table.
3. Delete actual table
4. Copy data back into actual table from temporary table.
5. Delete the `TEMPORARY TABLE`

You'll have to perform some destructive action on your actual table so make sure your `TEMPORARY TABLE` has what you want remaining before deleting anything from your actual table.

This is how you would create the `TEMPORARY TABLE`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE dups_with_oids
( id        integer
, model     text
, model_id  integer
, dependent_on_model text
) WITH OIDS;
```

Here is the `DELETE` query:

```
WITH temp AS
(
  SELECT  d.id AS keep
          , d.oid AS keep_oid
          , d2.id AS del
          , d2.oid AS del_oid
  FROM dups_with_oids d
    JOIN dups_with_oids d2 ON (d.id = d2.id AND d.oid < d2.oid)
) 
DELETE FROM dups_with_oids d
WHERE d.oid IN (SELECT temp.del_oid FROM temp);
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/88abb/17) to prove the theory.

I should add that if `id` were a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` these duplicates wouldn't have been possible.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i used the above method but with different code logic as below. reate table metric_temp as table metric;
delete from metric;

INSERT INTO metric(id,table_id,creator_id,name,description,archived,definition,created_at,updated_at,points_of_interest,caveats,how_is_this_calculated,show_in_getting_started)
SELECT 
    DISTINCT ON (id) id, table_id,creator_id,name,description,archived,definition,created_at,updated_at,points_of_interest,caveats,how_is_this_calculated,show_in_getting_started
FROM metric_temp; 

drop table metric_temp;

Comment: You're welcome. I like your `DISTINCT` method also. Probably quite a few ways to solve the problem. Good luck!